# How do I show alert message and disable the button if the input is not accepted on keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field that is listening to keyup event. It is checking the usernames uniqueness . I have a page full of forms that user have to fill in. One of it is to check if the username is unique.

The username has 3 restrictions.

1. Must be unique
2. Must be in lowercase.
3. Only alphanumeric is accepted.

I have no issue with the restrictions but I have a problem with displaying the alert message and disabling the proceed button.

In real development I use API to check the username, but you got the idea how I wanted to solve this problem. The real problem is, even if the username is  valid it is still showing the error message. It did not refresh the `isUsernameUnique` value.  How do I solve this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let isUsernameUnique = false;
  $('#nextButton').prop('disabled', false);
  $('#nextButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let year = $("#year").val();
    let email = $("#email").val();
    let username = $("#username").val();


    if (isUsernameUnique == true) {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "warning",
        text: 'Sorry this username already exists'
      });
      $('#nextButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }

    if (year != "" && email != "" && username != "") {
      $('#nextButton').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "warning",
        text: 'Please fill in all the information !'
      });
    }

  });


  $('#username').keyup(function() {
let checkUsername = $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase()).val();


    if (checkUsername == 'cindy90' || checkUsername == 'lilycollin' || checkUsername == 'adrian98') {
      $('#usernameValid').html(`<span style="color:red;"><b> (Invalid )</b></span>`);
      isUsernameUnique = false;
    } else
      $('#usernameValid').html(`<span style="color:green;"><b> (Valid) </b></span>`);
    isUsernameUnique = true;

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30 ">
  <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Username</i></b> <span id="usernameValid"></span></label><br>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="username" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) && (event.charCode != 32))">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30 ">
  <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Year</i></b></span></label><br>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <input class="from-control" type="text" id="year">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 mb-30 ">
  <label><b><span style="color:#e60000;">*</span> Email</i></b></span></label><br>
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <input class="from-control" type="email" id="email">
  </div>
</div>

<button id="nextButton">Next</button>
```

Comment: in your keyup function you appear to be setting your true and false values for isUsernameUnique the wrong way around. true when should be false and vice versa.

Comment: Are you considering `cindy90, lilycollin..` as valid username or invalid? Do you want to show `Swal` alert on keyUp?

Comment: @WdeVlam i will update the latest snippet

Comment: @navnath invalid username, is it possible to put the swal on the keyup ? I have tried that but it keep showing me the popup even user havent finish typing it. And I want to prevent from ignoring the swal message

Comment: @WdeVlam updated, but it still not refreshing the `isUsernameUnique` if user have put the existed username, then they removed and put the new name. the message still showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things

I suggest to make small functions that do one or two things only
I also suggest to use the submit event instead of the click event to test the validity

Actually doing that will make some of the things unnecessary

```js
const checkUser = () => {
  const checkUsername = $("#username").val().trim().toLowerCase();
  if (!checkUsername) return true
  const isUsernameUnique = !['cindy90', 'lilycollin', 'adrian98'].includes(checkUsername)
  if (isUsernameUnique)
    $('#usernameValid').html(`<span style="color:green;"><b> (Valid) </b></span>`);
  else
    $('#usernameValid').html(`<span style="color:red;"><b> (Invalid )</b></span>`);
  if (!isUsernameUnique) {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: "warning",
      text: 'Sorry this username already exists'
    });
  }

  return isUsernameUnique;
}

const checkEntries = () => {
  let year = $("#year").val().trim();
  let email = $("#email").val().trim();
  let username = $("#username").val().trim();
  return year !== "" && email !== "" && username !== "";
}

const isValid = () => checkUser() && checkEntries();

$(function() {

  $('#username').on("input", checkUser)
  $('#myForm').on("submit", function(e) {


    if (!checkEntries()) {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: "warning",
        text: 'Please fill in all the information !'
      });
    }


    if (!isValid()) e.preventDefault();
  })
  $('#myForm').on("input", function(e) {
    $('#nextButton').prop('disabled', !isValid());
  })
  $('#nextButton').prop('disabled', !isValid());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-30 ">
    <label>
      <span style="color:#e60000;"><b>*</b></span> 
      <b><i>Username</i></b> <span id="usernameValid"></span></label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) && (event.charCode != 32))" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-30 ">
    <label><span style="color:#e60000;"><b>*</b></span><b><i>Year</i></b></label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="year">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 mb-30 ">
    <label><span style="color:#e60000;"><b>*</b></span><b><i>Email</i></b></label>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="nextButton">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: its working but i'm not getting the message `username exist` If I still want to show the message it that possible ?

Comment: Yes. See update - and I fixed your invalid HTML

Comment: that was incredible!!! I could never think of this. Thank u I'm gonna study this solution

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks superhero. I always like to read your code.

Comment: @mplungjan I have question. If I retrieving the username from the api and I have this `if(response.data.status == 'success')` I can declare it as variable `isUsernameUnique` right ? or it will be completely different idea ?

Comment: You can, but be aware of asynchronous result

Answer (score 0):

In keyup function Replace

```
let checkUsername = $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
```

With

```
let checkUsername = $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase()).val();
```

Comment: Do you need `swal` popup on `keyup`, but it will be weired to do that, on every keyup users will be frustrated. Instead you should show `swal` `onChange` event

Comment: I have tried to put `swal` on keyup but its not a great idea. you means I have to declare swal into another function. can u suggest the code ?

Comment: Does the above code works? Till then let me figure out code how you can add `swal`.

Comment: I have change the checkusername with your suggestion. but I still got the same output if user put invalid name click the next button the swal message got popup. then i remove the invalid name put the new one. I still got the same invalid username message. eventho the username is valid.

Comment: Try @mplungjan code. He is the man's man. solution finder.